# how to select id which is dynamically change in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

here is my html:

```html
<?php echo ($row['status'] == 1)? ?>
    <span id='slide_".$row['id']."' name="slid_id"  class='label label-danger'>Inactive</span>
    <?php : ?>
    <span id='slide_".$row['id']."' name="slid_id" class='label label-success'>Active</span>
    <?php ; ?>
```

here is my jquery code:

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $("span").click(function() 
   {
         
     var id = $(":input[name=slide_id]").val();
  alert(id);
   });
});
```

i didn't get anything , i want to get the

> ID & its dynamic generated value

of the span element and then perform some action like on click i want to change the status from active to inactive or vise versa.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like you're missing the closing parens on both of the functions.

Comment: check the HTML now mate :) thanks anyway

Comment: i can't understand you it means i abovestand you.

Answer (score 0):

`var id = $(":input[name=slide_id]").attr('id');` should do the job. `.val()` only returns the current value of input elements.

Comment: not working it return undefined :( while trying to get value of selected id

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is missing from the question, but eliminating the colon in your jQuery selector might do the trick in selecting an input field - i.e. `$("input[name=slide_id]").val()`.

If you want to get the ID attribute of a span element, this would work:

```
$('span_selector').attr('id');
```

Comment: html added mate please check and reply now :0

Comment: okay i change the HTML to this

<input type="hidden"  id = <? echo $row['id'] ?> name="slide_id">

now use this in jquery to get id as a attribute

$(this).attr(id);
which provide clicked span element id ;

Answer (score 0):

okay finally i got the way to solve this things. m just sharing this if anyone have same issue one day then this might helpful.

html codes:

```html
<tr class="tr">
    <td class="td">
        <div id="status">
            <?php

            echo ($row['status'] == 1)? 
            "<span id='".$row['id']."' class='label label-danger'>Inactive</span>":
            "<span id='".$row['id']."' class='label label-success'>Active</span>";
            ?>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

my jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#status > span") .click(function()
        {

            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            var tempelement = $(this);
            var texts = $(this).closest(".tr").find("#texts").val();
            var author = $(this).closest(".tr").find("#author").val();
            var status = $(this).text();
            $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'manage_feedback.php',
                    data: {id:id, texts:texts, author:author, status:status},
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        if (data == "Active")
                        {
                            $(tempelement).removeClass("label label-danger");
                            $(tempelement).addClass("label label-success");
                            $(tempelement).html(data);
                            alert('status changed');
                        }
                        else if (data == "Inactive")
                        {
                            $(tempelement).removeClass("label label-success");
                            $(tempelement).addClass("label label-danger");
                            $(tempelement).html(data);
                            alert('status changed');
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            alert(data);
                        }
                    }
            });
        });
```

php script

```html
//ajax status changer code
if (isset($_POST['id']) && isset($_POST['texts']) && isset($_POST['status']) && isset($_POST['author']))
{
 $id = $_POST['id'];
 $texts = trim($_POST['texts']);
 $author = trim($_POST['author']);
 $status = $_POST['status'];

 $qry = "SELECT count(id) as count FROM tbl_testimonials WHERE texts = '".$texts."'
   AND author = '".$author."' AND id != ".$id." ";
 $sql = mysql_query($qry);
 $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
 
 if ($data['count'] == 0)
 {
  if($status == 'Inactive')
  {
   $qry = "UPDATE tbl_testimonials SET status = 0 WHERE id = ".$id." " ;
   $sql = mysql_query($qry);
   if($sql == 1)
   {
    echo 'Active';
    exit;
   }
  }
  elseif ($status == 'Active')
  {
   $qry = "UPDATE tbl_testimonials SET status = 1 WHERE id = ".$id." " ;
   $sql = mysql_query($qry);
   if($sql == 1)
   {
    echo 'Inactive';
    exit;
   }
  }
 }
 else
 {
  echo "name already taken";
  exit;
 }
}
```

hope it will help someone.